# Calculation of higher values in C

Tags: c, long-integer

The following code is not working properly. I wanted it to print the sum of 2 billion + 2 billion. Even though I'm using `long` here, I can't get the answer correct.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){

long  a = 2000000000;
long  b = 2000000000;

printf("%li\n",a + b);

return 0;
}
```

When I run this program I get the value -294967296. I'm using VS Code IDE, Mingw compiler and windows version is windows 11.

Comment: What is `sizeof(long)`? On my system (MS VC) it is `4` the same as `int` (as it can be). For that reason it is pointless to ever use `long`.

Comment: Try using `long long` and `%lli` instead.

Comment: Try using `int_least64_t` from `<stdint.h>` instead of the ill-defined `long` and `long long` types.

Comment: @WeatherVane "pointless to ever use `long`" --> Certainly mostly true.  It is useful in file sizing as in `ftell()`, yet even that is dodgy as file sizes are known from time-to-time to exceed `LONG_MAX`. `short` also has limited uses.  `long, short` get [no respect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCVR_ajL_Eo).

Comment: Try using `unsigned long`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`long` is at *least* 32-bit and its range must span *at least* +/- 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 or +/-2,147,483,647.

On some machines a `long` is wider such as [-2<sup>63</sup> ...
2<sup>63</sup> - 1].

On OP's machine, it is [-2<sup>31</sup> ...  2<sup>31</sup> - 1].

---

For OP. `a + b` inccurs *signed integer* overflow which in *undefined behavior* (UB) as the sum of two `long` is outside the `long` range.  A common result is the sum is "wrapped" and results in a `long` of -294,967,296 although many other results are possible including code crash.

---

To handle sums like 4,000,000,000, perform the addition with `unsigned long` math with its *minimum* rage of [0 ... 2<sup>32</sup> - 1] or use `long long`.

```
// printf("%li\n",a + b);
printf("%lli\n",0LL + a + b);
```

Or ...

```
long long  a = 2000000000;
long long  b = 2000000000;
printf("%lli\n",a + b);
```

Answer (score 2):

The size of `long` integer is not fixed unlike other data types. It varies from architectures, operating system and even with compiler that we are using. In some of the systems it behaves like an int data type or a long long data type as follows:

```sh
  OS               Architecture          Size
Windows       IA-32                     4 bytes
Windows       Intel® 64 or IA-64        4 bytes
Linux         IA-32                     4 bytes
Linux         Intel® 64 or IA-64        8 bytes
Mac OS X      IA-32                     4 bytes
Mac OS X      Intel® 64 or IA-64        8 bytes
```

`long` might be 32 bit in your case. To avoid this confusion, use `stdint` where you can be sure of the sizes and also portable

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<inttypes.h>

int main(void){

    int64_t  a = 2000000000;
    int64_t  b = 2000000000;

    // printf("%lli\n",a + b);
    printf("res = %" PRI64d "!\n", a+b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `long` is not `int`. It may have the same size and width as `int`, but they are always different types.

Comment: `"%lli"` should not be used to convert `int64_t`. A correct method is to include `<inttypes.h>` and use `"%" PRI64d "\n"`l

Comment: *"The size of long integer is not fixed unlike other data types."* - You should really reword that. Unlike what other data types? Niether `int` nor `short` is fixed. `char` is fixed in the sense that it's always one byte, but it's specified to have *at least* 8 bits.

Comment: Re “The size of `long` integer is not fixed unlike other data types”: The C standard does not fix the sizes or widths of any of the integer data types except for aspects of `_Bool`. `signed char` must be at least eight bits but may be wider. `short int` must be at least as wide as `signed char` and as least 16 bits but may be wider. `int` must be at least as wide as `short char` and at least 16 bits but may be wider. `long int` must be at least as wide as `int` and at least 32 bits but may be wider. `long long int` must be at least as wide as `long int` and at least 64 bits but may be wider.

Comment: balu, "Windows  Intel® 64 or IA-64  4 bytes" incorrectly implies the size is an OS selection. It is a _compiler_ selection influenced by the OS.   Example: _gcc_ on a Windows 64 may use a 64-bit `long`.

Answer (score -3):

The max size of a long may be the same as an int, you should use long long instead.

[Integer size in C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/cpp-integer-limits?view=msvc-170)

Comment: The size of `long` ***may*** be the same as `int`. It depends on compiler, target system, and perhaps other factors.

Comment: The documentation linked only concerns Microsoft's compiler, the compiler used by OP is not this one.

Comment: If OP is using GCC, long value may be the same [GCC size](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Integer-variables.html)

Comment: *"The max size of a long is the same as an int"* - This is not true. At least not in the general case. You should be more clear what you mean.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).